# Como pasar valor dinámico a un canvas de Chart.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, chart.js

Compañeros llevo varias horas tratando de implementar el gráfico de Chartjs con valores reales. La estructura que pide es la siguiente

```js
<script>
                var miCanvas = document.getElementById('grfId').getContext('2d');
                var chart = new Chart(miCanvas, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: ['etiqueta1','etiqueta2','etiqueta3'],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Titulo de grafico',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,20,55)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(255,255,0)',
                                data: [2, 4, 8]
                            }]
                    }
                });

            </script>
```

donde label es un array de string con formato de texto encomillado

Mi controller tengo :

```
var listainventario = (from b in db.Tabla select b.Cantidad).Take(7).OrderByDescending(b => b.Value).ToList();
                var listadescripcion = (from b in db.Tabla select b.Descripcion).Take(7).ToList();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int couter = listadescripcion.Count-1;
                for (int i = 0; i < couter; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append("'" + listadescripcion[i] + "',");
                }
                sb.Append("'" + listadescripcion[couter - 1]+"'");
                ViewBag.mEtiquetas =sb; //new string[] { "peptopril", "diclofenaco", "genoprasol" };
return View(mimodelo);
```

Mi vista:

```
    <div>
                <canvas id="grfInventario" width="800" height="350"></canvas>
            </div>
   <script>
                var miCanvas = document.getElementById('grfInventario').getContext('2d');
                var chart = new Chart(miCanvas, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: [@ViewBag.mEtiquetas],
                        datasets: [
                            {
                                label: 'Demanda de productos',
                                backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,20,55)',
                                borderColor: 'rgb(255,255,0)',
                                data: [2, 4, 8,7,1,11,5]
                            }]
                    }
                });

            </script>
```

Intenté pasar mi lista como 'ViewBag.Etiquetas=listadescripcion.ToArray(); y en la vista recuperar con label: [(List)@ViewBag.Etiquetas] pero no funcionó. Luego decidí usar StringBuilder desde codigo ;Por lo que el renderizado me genera una lista con caracteres hexadecimales y el label de la librería no enlaza esos valores

Comment: Que te aparece en `labels` cuando haces eso?

Comment: osea el html se genera  labels: [&#39;Aspirina  240ml&#39;,&#39;Insulina-78&#39; y el div deja un espacio en el body para el grafico, pero no lo dibuja

Comment: intenta esto: `sb.Append("\'" + listadescripcion[i] + "\',");`

Comment: sigue generando el hexadecimal en html @alanfcm , si intento var strArray=ViewBag.mEtiquetas; strArray = strArray.replace("&#39;", "'");} en razor me manda que stringBuilder no contiene una definicio de replace

Answer (score 0):

resulta que el control chartjs solo funciona con variables de javascript, no podemos injectar variables razor directamente;como `@{(List<string>)ViewBag.Etiquetas;}` aunque teóricamente esté correcto.La solución pasa por almacenar ese arreglo en un objeto js como un  `var array = [];` mediante una petición ajax logramos el acometido; almacenando nuevamente en un var datos y recorrerlo con `for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){ array.push(datos[i])}`.El ultimo truco es no usar corchetes al asignar esa variable en la declaración de labels: